# UFT - Identifying PAGE class as WINOBJECT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

Currently I am working on a desktop application which is developed in power builder. Earlier below code line used to work without any issue. 
`PbWindow().PbWindow().ActiveX().Page().Highlight`

Since last week, UFT identifying **Page** class as **WinObject**. Now current hierarchy is `PbWindow->PbWindow->ActiveX->WinObject`.

There is table on this page from which we are fetching the information for validation purpose. But due to this issue we are not able to do anything.

We got confirmation that developer hasn't change the code. 
What could be an issue & what is the solution for this?

Comment: Sometimes it happens even for web application too. Close your application and UFT. Launch UFT before you open your application, and everything should work fine. Oh, btw make sure necessary add-ins are selected.

Comment: Hi Barney, Thanks for you reply. We have tried all these ways & selected all required add-ins but it is not working.

Comment: Below are few things you can try,

1) Ask someone else to log in to the system and see if UFT is identifying the Page with other Windows profiles.
2) Uninstall and reinstall Powerbuilder plugin.
3) Check with developers if they have upgraded the version of powerbuilder.
4) Check if there are any patches which are available for powerbuilder.
5) Uninstall and reinstall UFT.